# When to ask for login?

Tags: login, e-commerce, registration

I own an online store for video games and use the Stripe API for handling payments.

This is the current order of events: Add to cart → Checkout → Enter Card Info → Charge → Download Item. To battle piracy, I recently installed a login page into the games to detect whether the user has bought them.

Because of this, I need to get game buyers to login, but due to limitations in my installation of Stripe, I can't put the login between the checkout and enter card info before checkout.

In terms of UX, which other place would be the best place to ask the user to login?

Comment: It's not possible to determine when the user clicks "Checkout" whether or not they are logged in? It seems like you could detect at that point and redirect them to a login page if necessary, completely separate from whatever Stripe limitations you have.

Comment: You could also drop a cookie at the point the redirect occurs containing the items in the basket and any other checkout information that you can modify and use to return them to the checkout with a complete basket and the relevant details pre filled in the checkout form.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying a different way of verifying the purchases? Perhaps a SMS or a token that comes with the game invoice and is attached to the account. This way, the user needs the code/pin to log in the game.

Answer (score 0):

based on this process flow, Add to cart → Checkout → Enter Card Info → Charge → Download Item, I’d suggest putting the login sequence once the user clicks Add to cart (or save/ bookmark item if there’s any).

The reasons for doing so are

1. it allows you as an owner to track the sales funnel/ conversion on how the buyer decides to purchase the game (ie the time taken to check out, or if users also pick last minute buys before checkout, or if your suggested games work well)
2. putting the login at the onset reduces the amount of questions in the user’s mind - imagine if you have already decided to make payment and you are expected to put in your credit card info, and then the system prompts a login, I’d feel the login process disruptive and may abandon the purchase, or I may question why do I need to login to the system when making a purchase?
3. lastly, putting the login when the user Add to cart allows users to feel that the login is necessary to retrieve the cart items in case the internet connection is interrupted (intentionally or not).